# gnuplot 2d heatmap basic format

Tags: gnuplot

very new to gnuplot.

Data: 5 particles in the system. I am tracking the  distance among all of them at varied time points. want to generate a heatmap of their proximity. http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html says generation with X Y Z or Z values only. I do not understand whats the X and Y and Z here:

```
5 4 3 1 0  First column:x ? Second column y? and various z values in column 
2 2 0 0 1  3,4,5 ...?
0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 2 3
0 1 2 4 3
```

For my study, I have a matrix (as one set)

```
(particle)--->1   2      3     4      5
   |
    1         0   1.2    2.4   7.5   3.4
    2        1.2    0      4     8.9   3
    3        2.4    4      0     2     8
    4        7.5    8.9    2     0     6
    5        3.4    3      8     6     0 
(next set)
------------similar to above
```

and so on .....

I am confused what should be the format of my ASCII data?
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Heat maps are typically used to visualize functions of two variables x and y, where x and y are the axes.

So the way you interpret it is correct, but the `matrix with image` style actually inverts the points because it starts printing at (0,0) and then adds elements in the positive coordinate directions.
So if your file (lets call it `data.dat`) looks like this:

```
0    1.2    2.4   7.5   3.4
1.2  0      4     8.9   3
2.4  4      0     2     8
7.5  8.9    2     0     6
3.4  3      8     6     0
```

You can get a plot like this:

[image: YourPlot]

By calling `plot "<tail -r data.dat" matrix w ima`